# Django - allow url only to be accessed from a specific page

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I have a form for the user to fill out at < home >/data. 
However, I want the user to only be able to access the form if they agree to certain terms, located at < home >/terms.

Is there a way to ensure that the only way to access < home >/data is from the agree button on < home >/terms? I.e. just typing in < home >/data to the address bar should throw an error or redirect to terms.

In case it matters, I'm not storing users (I'm using session data).

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `referer` header (`request.META['HTTP_REFERER']`)to determine which page the user came from. Your view can read this header and deny access if it doesn't exist / redirect back to your terms page.

For something a bit more reliable, if you're already using session data, you can store a flag in the session upon the user clicking the "agree" button on the terms page. Perhaps that does a form POST, you set a flag in the session that they agreed, and the view redirects to the /data page.

On the /data view, you can redirect back to the terms page if this flag isn't detected in the session.

Comment: Setting a flag on their session when the first view is called, then flipping it back off after the second (protected) view is called is perfect. 